# Gaussian curvature of $S^3$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, curvature

It is easy to see that Gauss curvature of $S^2$ is $1/R^2$. How can we find the Gaussian curvature of $S^3$? What about $S^n$ in general?

Comment: By "Gauss curvature" of a sphere (of radius $R$?) do you mean (i) [sectional curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sectional_curvature) $1/R^{2}$, (ii) the product $1/R^{n}$ of the normal curvatures when the round sphere is embedded in Euclidean space in the usual way, or (iii) something else?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Sorry, it is actually "Gaussian curvature", which is a product of principal curvatures.

Comment: The gaussian curvature is defined for surfaces only, i.e. a two-dimensional smooth manifolds. The sphere $S^3$ has dimension three, so you have to look for some generalizations of gaussian curvature. This wikipedia article discusses all sort of definitions of curvatures: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature_of_Riemannian_manifolds

Comment: @Spenser -- the Gaussian curvature is defined for any hypersurface in a Riemannian manifold, once a unit normal is chosen. It's the determinant of the (scalar) second fundamental form, or equivalently the product of the principal curvatures.